# WebApiConfig.Configure() does not exist (Auth0/OWIN)

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I am currently following this tutorial for implementing Auth0 in my WebApi, https://community.auth0.com/t/asp-net-web-api-tutorial/7335.

In the Startup class they say to implement WebApiConfig.Configure(app).

But the method does not exist. What is this method suppose to contain.

Startup.cs

```js
public class Startup {
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
   var domain = $"https://{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0Domain"]}/";
   var apiIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Auth0ApiIdentifier"];

   var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);
   app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions {
     AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
     TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
      ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
      ValidIssuer = domain,
      IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) =>   keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid)
     }
    });

   // Configure Web API
   WebApiConfig.Configure(app);
  }
 }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```js
public static class WebApiConfig {
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
   // Web API configuration and services

   // Web API routes
   config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
  }

  internal static void Configure(IAppBuilder app) {
   throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
 }
```

Comment: The method `WebApiConfig.Configure()` is in place and actually has some configuration inside: https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-aspnet-owin-webapi-samples/blob/master/Quickstart/01-Authorization/WebApi/WebApi/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs

Comment: Your `WebApiConfig` class looks similar but a bit different.

Comment: Added in the Configure method to my WebApiConfig only to lead to find out that app.UseWebApi method, called in the Configure method, does not exist.

Comment: The issue is not clear. Based on the code from your question it should throw `NotImplementedException`. What do you mean by "does not exist"?